# Generar repositorios a partir de herencia JPA BBDD

Tags: java, thymeleaf

Dispongo de una clase abstracta, llamada Reforma y de ella heredan otras 2 clases hijas, que en este caso son Aseos y Cocina.

Esta es la clase Reforma:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="reforma")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
public abstract class Reforma {

public static final String PREFIJO = "RE";

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
protected long id_reforma;

protected String referencia;

protected float largo;

protected float ancho;

protected float alto;

protected float precio_azulejo_m2;

protected int modif_instalacion;

@OneToOne(mappedBy="reforma")
private Presupuesto presupuesto;

public Reforma() {
    super();
}

public Reforma(long id_reforma, String referencia, float largo, float ancho, float alto, float precio_azulejo_m2,
        int modif_instalacion) {
    super();
    this.id_reforma = id_reforma;
    this.referencia = referencia;
    this.largo = largo;
    this.ancho = ancho;
    this.alto = alto;
    this.precio_azulejo_m2 = precio_azulejo_m2;
    this.modif_instalacion = modif_instalacion;
}

public long getId_reforma() {
    return id_reforma;
}

public void setId_reforma(long id_reforma) {
    this.id_reforma = id_reforma;
}

public String getReferencia() {
    return PREFIJO + this.id_reforma;
}

public float getLargo() {
    return largo;
}

public void setLargo(float largo) {
    this.largo = largo;
}

public float getAncho() {
    return ancho;
}

public void setAncho(float ancho) {
    this.ancho = ancho;
}

public float getAlto() {
    return alto;
}

public void setAlto(float alto) {
    this.alto = alto;
}

public float getPrecio_azulejo_m2() {
    return precio_azulejo_m2;
}

public void setPrecio_azulejo_m2(float precio_azulejo_m2) {
    this.precio_azulejo_m2 = precio_azulejo_m2;
}

public long getModif_instalacion() {
    return modif_instalacion;
}

public void setModif_instalacion(int modif_instalacion) {
    this.modif_instalacion = modif_instalacion;
}

}
```

Y estas son las otras 2:
Aseos:

```
@Entity
public class Aseos extends Reforma {

public static final String SUFIJO = "A";
private int num_sanitarios;

public Aseos() {
    super();
}

public Aseos(long id_reforma, String referencia, float largo, float ancho, float alto, float precio_azulejo_m2,
        int modif_instalacion, int num_sanitarios) {
    super(id_reforma, referencia, largo, ancho, alto, precio_azulejo_m2, modif_instalacion);
    this.num_sanitarios = num_sanitarios;
}

public String getReferenciaAseo() {
    return getReferencia() + SUFIJO;
    
}

public String getCodigo_Ref() {
    return PREFIJO + Long.toString(getId_reforma()) + SUFIJO;
}

public int getNum_sanitarios() {
    return num_sanitarios;
}

public void setNum_sanitarios(int num_sanitarios) {
    this.num_sanitarios = num_sanitarios;
}

}
```

Y Cocina:

```
@Entity
public class Cocina extends Reforma {

public static final String SUFIJO = "CO";
private int mueble_mtr_lineales;
private int encimera_mtr_lineales;

public Cocina() {
    super();
}

public Cocina(long id_reforma, String referencia, float largo, float ancho, float alto, float precio_azulejo_m2,
        int modif_instalacion, int mueble_mtr_lineales, int encimera_mtr_lineales) {
    super(id_reforma, referencia, largo, ancho, alto, precio_azulejo_m2, modif_instalacion);
    this.mueble_mtr_lineales = mueble_mtr_lineales;
    this.encimera_mtr_lineales = encimera_mtr_lineales;
}

public String getReferenciaCocina() {
    return getReferencia() + SUFIJO;
}

public int getMueble_mtr_lineales() {
    return mueble_mtr_lineales;
}

public void setMueble_mtr_lineales(int mueble_mtr_lineales) {
    this.mueble_mtr_lineales = mueble_mtr_lineales;
}

public int getEncimera_mtr_lineales() {
    return encimera_mtr_lineales;
}

public void setEncimera_mtr_lineales(int encimera_mtr_lineales) {
    this.encimera_mtr_lineales = encimera_mtr_lineales;
}

}
```

A raíz de estas, tengo que guardar en mi base de datos registros con estos datos, que se guardan en una tabla madre (reforma) y luego hace un join con las tablas aseos y cocina. La duda me surge a la hora de construir los repositorios que conectan con la misma. ¿Debería construir un repositorio para todas las clases, hacer un repositorio por clase o hacer que cada clase hija tenga su repositorio? ¿Cómo construyo este repositorio a partir de estas relaciones de herencia?